# How to get distinct items from Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Hyperlinks

Tags: c#, .net, linq, office-interop, powerpoint-2013

Hi can somebody help to get distinct items from Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Hyperlinks using LINQ on the basis of Hyperlink.TextToDisplay and Hyperlink.Address. I want to have items with distinct values for Address and TextToDisplay.

This is what I have tried

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Hyperlinks links = links.Cast<Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Hyperlink>().Select(p=>p.TextToDisplay).Distinct().ToList();
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var distinctLinks = links
    .Cast<Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Hyperlink>()
    .GroupBy(x => new {x.TextToDisplay, x.Address})
    .Select(x => x.First())
    .ToList();
```